# Getting "error validating access token" error using Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, token

After a few days of having my own app run on my phone I start getting this error when requseting a friend list from Facebook: "error validating access token"

I'm using the Facebook SDK with the single signon turned off ( just using the WebView login ).

When I logoff and then log back in - everything is fine again.

What does one do about this error and where does it come from?

Answer (score 0):

It means that your token has expire. To avoid that problem you can ask for the permission "offline_access" so that you have a token that never expire.